# Updating Line and Polygon in Geoserver via Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs-t

I've been trying to update point, line and polygon in GeoServer via Leaflet. I can update point via WFS-T but I have a problem for updating line and polygon.

My code for updating point is something like this :

```
var postData = 
                '<wfs:Transaction\n'
              + '  service="WFS"\n'
              + '  version="1.1.0"\n'
              + '  xmlns:grp="http://lab.georepublic.info"\n'
              + '  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\n'
              + '  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\n'
              + '  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"\n'
              + '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n'
              + '  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs\n'
              + '                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">\n'
              + '  <wfs:Update typeName="grp:points">\n'
              + '    <wfs:Property>\n'
              + '      <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>\n'
              + '      <wfs:Value>\n'
              + '        <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">\n'
              + '          <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">' + point.getLatLng().lat + ',' + 
                                point.getLatLng().lng + '</gml:coordinates>\n'
              + '        </gml:Point>\n'
              + '      </wfs:Value>\n'
              + '    </wfs:Property>\n'
              + '    <ogc:Filter>\n'
              + '      <PropertyIsEqualTo>\n'
              + '        <PropertyName>pid</PropertyName>\n'
              + '        <Literal>' + point.options.pid + '</Literal>\n'
              + '      </PropertyIsEqualTo>\n'
              + '    </ogc:Filter>\n'
              + '  </wfs:Update>\n'
              + '</wfs:Transaction>';
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: gs.wfs,
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                data: postData,
                //TODO: Error handling
                success: function(xml) {    
                    //TODO: User feedback
                }
            });
```

What is the sample code for updating line and polygon?

Comment: Why don't you, instead of fighting with `WFS-T` transaction syntax, try Leaflet plugin `Leaflet-WFST`: https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST.

Comment: It will be exactly the same but with a line or a polygon in the GML - but as @TomazicM says use a prebuilt module to do the heavy lifting

Comment: TomazicM tnx. I have used this plugin but I need to send the other fields along with geom field. So I should make my XML dynamically and this plugin doesn't have such ability as far as i know.

Comment: Then, if for example you have `L.polyline` line, use `getLatLngs()` method to extract array of coordinates, loop through them end construct your GML `gml:LineString`.